# Tableau - Combining multiple line graphs into single plot

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I am trying to get all my lines to overlap on a single graph. How would I go about doing this? Here is what I managed to get so far:

[image: Tableau Screen]

And when I say overlap, I mean something similar to this:
[image: R Example]

Here is more information about my data:

Each of the attributes (e.g. 'Intro', 'Flair') have the following integers in the data: 1,2,3,4 with an associated pcttip (tip percentage) as a decimal number.

I have manually right clicked on each of the measures in the columns area and changed them to "dimension".

The dataset can be found here if you would like to try: https://www.dropbox.com/s/je72hbso2tzby60/Tableau_data_2.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Tableau fairly easily. You need to pivot some of your data.

1. Click on the data source in the top-left and select Edit Data Source
2. In the bottom pane, where your data is previewed, select/highlight each of the fields that you want measured (Intro, Flair, etc.)
3. Right-Click with those fields selected and click Pivot
4. When you return to your sheet, you will see a new dimension field and measure field for your pivot.
5. Add [Pivot field values] to the Columns section - make sure this is set to 'Dimension' and 'Continuous'
6. Add [Pivot field names] to the Color card

**Pivot**
[image: Pivot]

**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: I'm not sure what data is being used in this example but one thing to note is that pivot only works on text data sources _'pivot the data in your Microsoft Excel and text file data sources from crosstab format'_

Answer (score 0):

Drag 'Repeat' pill to the X-axis on 'Intro' then drag the other pills into 'Intro'

Something similar to this: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/buildexamples_line.html

Comment: Have you tested that? It doesn't work because it requires you use an aggregation (SUM, AVG, etc.), which will not get the OP what they need.